# display page then read input, get data from mysql and display output ... one php script or two?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've written a stock control system for my little business using html/javascript and mysql and although it works I'm not sure i've coded it the right way.
When I run the script, I test $_POST being empty, if so an input field (sku) is displayed and underneath that a (hidden) empty table, and a button which when clicked executes the same script.
Next time in, $_POST is filled, so the script reads a mysql database using the sku entered, and gets the relevant data, un-hides(!) the html table, populates it and displays the data.

I've added more code so that I can modify the displayed data in the html table and then update the database.

Is this the right/recommended way to do it, or should the initial screen be one script and then mysql processing another script, then (maybe) back to the first script to display the data.
Its only me thats using it, but would like to make sure I'm doing it right !
Thanks in advance

Comment: In very simple scripts, you can do that this way - but normaly you would split this tasks, because, if you want to extend your application and you have complicated logic structure ( in your script, the checkings against _POST ) you will bite into your desk, because with each extend it will be harder and harder to implement.

So in your case, i would split that into a reader.php, writer.php and display.php script, with each will communicate with each other.

Comment: Blimey that was quick !.. Yes I have one or two bite marks on the desk already... I'll split it into separate scripts. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: This is a balancing act we all play. Take it in the total opposite direction. Is it wrong to put 1 line of code per file and have 100 files for 100 lines of code. YES! I usually advocate for only making things as complex as they need to be. That said I would not render your table hidden. Just do not render it at all when your not using it. But @rebru is correct encapsulating your functionality to multiple files has many benefits until it doesn't :)

Comment: Yep, fair point, when I split the processes I'll remove the hidden table from the initlal display. I suppose this is where planning what I wanted to do first, would have helped, but I'm bolting bits on as I learn about them.. great fun !